# Rewriting a field in organic group member view

Tags: organic-groups, views

I am not sure if this is possible..

My organic group 'member view' filters all the members of a particular group.
I have created the view so that the first member gets listed in a sidebar to become a link  'members' pointing to the complete member list for the current group.

The same view is used for a different grouptype.
So the first member gets listed as a link as well.
However with this grouptype i want my 'first member link' to be 'rewritten' as 'friends' instead of 'members'

Can this be done with one view?

I have tried using two fields to display rewriting one as 'members' and the other as 'friends'. Without succes i tried finding a proper relationship for them....

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

did you try https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional?

it allows to conditionally format/rewrite the output of certain views fields depending on the value of other fields that you have added in your view.